# I have create new extension and placed in market place but it give error MFTF AdminCreateAndEditConfigurableProductSettingsTest is broken

Tags: php, path, namespaces, extension-methods, magento-2.3

error MFTF AdminCreateAndEditConfigurableProductSettingsTest is broken.

//Below my composer.json file

```
{
    "name": "grazitti/minicart",
    "description": "The Advance Mini Cart by Grazitti Interactive upgrades a mini cart to your store and offers upselling functionality with specific product recommendations to improve your sales.",
    "version": "1.0.1",
    "type": "magento2-module",
    "keywords": ["Advance mini cart","magento 2 custom mini cart","magento 2 minicart extension","Drawer minicart","Quick Cart","Mini Cart Magento","Mini Cart Magento 2","Upgrade Mini Cart","free magento 2 mini cart extension","magento 2 sidebar cart","Advanced Cart Drawer"],
    "homepage": "https://www.grazitti.com/",
    "license": "proprietary",
    "authors": [
        {
        "name": "Grazitti Interactive",
        "email": "info@grazitti.com",
        "homepage": "https://www.grazitti.com/",
        "role": "Developer"
        }
    ],
    "support": {
        "email": "maginate@grazitti.com"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": { "Grazitti\\Minicart\\": "" },
        "files": [ "registration.php" ]
    }
}
```

screenshot of error

https://i.stack.imgur.com/maFzs.png

Comment: Did you resolve it? I have the same issue. But the extension has been approved and the new version is available on the marketplace.